# Get invalid_grant error when attempting to refresh a token

Tags: node.js, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am developing a node.js application which uses outlook rest API to fetch the mails. I am using [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/graph/auth-v2-user) API.

I am trying to refresh the token using the following request. I am using request npm to call the API

```
{
    url: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant-id}/oauth2/v2.0/token',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
    formData:
    {
        scope: 'offline_access User.Read Mail.Read',
        client_id: 'c251b61b-c6db-4f64-89bd-7009444d1bc8',
        grant_type: 'refresh_token',
        redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:3000/myurl',
        refresh_token: 'refresh-token',
        client_secret: 'cli-secret'
     }
}
```

but getting the following error

```
{
  "error": "invalid_grant",
  "error_description": "AADSTS9002313: Invalid request. Request is malformed or  invalid.745ec0500",
  "correlation_id": "a2d87f11-0671-41f1-a5e7-654f1796c3d1"
}
```

I have also tried with adding `Content-length` in headers and appending all variables into a string using `&` and `=` and sending that in the body, but I got the same error. I am getting an `access-token` successfully.

Comment: What does your initial call to retrieve the `access_token` look like?

Answer (score 3):

So far I know you are trying to get refresh token in the wrong way.

As the error said, you are trying in incorrect `grant_type`.

As per your given [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/graph/auth-v2-user#3-get-a-token) reference the `grant_type` should be `authorization_code`. Once you would get your `Code` then you need to use it for achieving `access token`and `refresh token`.

When your access token would expired then you have to use the refresh token to get a new access token as [document explains](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/graph/auth-v2-user#5-use-the-refresh-token-to-get-a-new-access-token).

In that case try with `response_type=code` format.

**Request For Code:**

[image]

**Get Code In Postman Console:**

[image]

**Request For Access And Refresh Token With Code:**

[image]

**Get Access And Refresh Token By Code:**

[image]

**Get Refresh Token When Access Token Expired:**

[image]

**Note:** This this the exact way how you would get `authorization code` and with this code how to get `access token` along with `refresh token` finally how to renew token with the `refresh token` when the
`access token` expired!

Answer (score 1):

When you generate the access token the first time that time you also get the refresh token. you have to store that token anywhere you can also store it in a database or a txt file.

```
 $post_params_refresh = array(
"grant_type" => "refresh_token",
"client_id" => 'ReplaceYourClientId',
"refresh_token" => 'ReplaceYourOldRefreshToken',
"client_secret" => 'ReplaceYourClientSecretKey',
'scope' => 'https://graph.microsoft.com/User.ReadWrite.All',
);
$refreshTokenUrl = "https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/v2.0/token";
$curl_refresh = curl_init($refreshTokenUrl);
curl_setopt($curl_refresh, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl_refresh, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_params_refresh);
curl_setopt($curl_refresh, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));
curl_setopt($curl_refresh, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($curl_refresh, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curl_refresh, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
curl_setopt($curl_refresh, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$response_refresh = curl_exec($curl_refresh);
$arrResponseRefresh = json_decode($response_refresh);
$accessToken = $arrResponseRefresh->access_token;
$refreshToken = $arrResponseRefresh->refresh_token;
```

You get a new refresh token using this curl method and update this refresh token to the old token which you stored previously.